# Can't update multi records in extjs

Tags: extjs4

I create a button handler like that:

```
function(){
        var selection = grid_mt_p.getView().getSelectionModel().getSelection();
        /*var len = selection.length;
        for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
            selection[i].set('ma_phong', "");
        }*/
        if (Ext.isArray(selection)) {
            Ext.each(selection, function(s) {
                s.set({ma_phong: ""});
            });
        }
    }
```

But when I click the button, it just change ma_phong of the first selection. Is my code wrong or I forget something?

Comment: Did you check whether id's are same?

Comment: yes. I use s.get("ma_phong"); and it show correct value

Comment: ok. I just need to add s.commit(); after s.set({ma_phong: ""});